# Google Text To Speech for Hindi Language, not working now

Tags: android, text-to-speech, hindi, google-text-to-speech

i am trying to use Google's Text to speech engine for Hindi language in android. When i pass Hindi text in TextToSpeech's speak() method, it used to play the audio using the Networktts. This used to work fine before an update to Google Text to speech app which got published on 27th May 2014. After that it has stopped working. When i examined the logcat entries i found that earlier it used to connect to

```
I/GoogleTTSService(12454): Creating Google TTS service, version 2.4.3.1227136
```

and returned language code 0. Hindi TTS would work fine.
While now it connect to

```
I/GoogleTTSService(11289): Creating Google TTS service, version 3.1.3.1162895
```

and it returns language code -2. Now it doesn't work.

If i uninstall the updates of Google Text to speech app then it rollbacks to version 2.4.3.1227136 and Hindi Text to speech works again.

Any idea how can i work with Hindi using the latest version of Google Text to speech?

Thanks

Comment: can provide code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Text to Speech engine got updated today and Hindi is now supported for online synthesis as well as offline synthesis.